# using external libraries in Qt/Symbian

Tags: qt, symbian, nokia

To get Facebook integration in our Nokia Symbian application we intend to use this library:
http://gitorious.org/qfacebookconnect

It is not otherwise working completely correctly, but it's a good start.

I have my project (.pro and .cpp files, using Qt Creator), which works fine in the emulator. I included this libqfacebook in the project in this way (in the .pro file):

```
LIBS += -LC:\projects\Pristop\Nokia\facebook_lib\libqfacebook-build-simulator\debug -lqfacebookconnect

INCLUDEPATH += C:\projects\Pristop\Nokia\facebook_lib\qfacebookconnect\inc
```

It works fine in the emulator. I use Qt Creator for everything, also to build libqfacebook. But if I want to test the application on a real phone,  so to prepare a .sis file, I get this error:

```
:: error: No rule to make target `\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\release\armv5\LIB\qfacebookconnect.dso', needed by `\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\release\gcce\udeb\DogajaItak.exe'.  Stop.
```

So I need to get a .dso file based on the source code of the qfacebookconnect library. For the emulator .lib and .pdb were enough. Obviously the difference is that .dso is arm while .lib & .pdb are x86.

If I try to configure qfacebookconnect to build for the phone, I get this error:

```
Makefile:232: error: PKG file does not exist, 'sis' and 'installer_sis' target are only supported for executables or projects with DEPLOYMENT statement.  Stop.
```

It is correct that I do not want a .sis, all I want is a .dso.
If I go to Projects->Build Settings for Symbian Device for qfacebookconnect and I remove the build step "create SIS package" for qfacebookconnect, there is no error anymore, but I still don't believe it built a .dso for me.

So the question is how to configure Qt Creator or the .pro file to build me a .dso, or how to include external libraries in my .sis in another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to freeze the library..

I found all the information there:
https://code.google.com/p/qfacebookconnect/issues/detail?id=13